# Spring Data Redis - How to detect a failover to resubscribe to channels

Tags: spring, lettuce, redis-sentinel

I'm using Spring Data Redis with Redis Sentinel and subscribe to keyspace event notifications.
How to detect when a switch to a new master occurs as a result of a failover so that I can resubscribe to the required channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to manually detect failovers and resubscribe to channels when that happens, since Lettuce does that by itself (see `StatefulRedisPubSubConnectionImpl#activated()`).

Comment: Is this possible using Jedis ?